# My Question C# Setting a Status to User (Online/Idle) Discord.NET 1.0.2

Tags: c#, status, discord.net

I want to set a status to discord account. It connected to token.
My problem is on visual studio.
I tried to set `SetGameAsync`, and it worked. But when i tried to set a status like "Idle" or "Online" of User account, Its not working. How can i set status of a person?

I tried to 2 codes. There are:
`Client.CurrentUser.Status(UserStatus.Idle);`,
`Client.SetStatusAsync(UserStatus.Idle);`

I know there is no set option for `SetStatusAsync`. But there is no set option for `SetGameAsync` too. But it can.

Comment: This should work just fine in the scenario of a bot. Are you perhaps referring to a user bot here?

Comment: I want to set status for a user. Not bot.

Comment: You are not supposed to perform any action on behalf of an user, see [our official stance on this](https://docs.stillu.cc/faq/basics/client-basics.html#my-client-keeps-returning-401-upon-logging-in).

Comment: You said its not supposed. But it's not impossible, right?

Comment: It's not impossible; however, it is discouraged, as you risk banning your account.

Comment: im getting risk. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

### Setting Status for Client

See the [official documentation](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.WebSocket.DiscordSocketClient.html#Discord_WebSocket_DiscordSocketClient_SetStatusAsync_Discord_UserStatus_) on the method `SetStatusAsync`, where it is said that the method belongs to the class `DiscordSocketClient`, meaning in your context, you should be doing `client.SetStatusAsync`.

### Self-botting

Additionally, Discord.NET itself does not condone the use of "self-botting" as described in its [FAQ](https://docs.stillu.cc/faq/basics/client-basics.html#my-client-keeps-returning-401-upon-logging-in), hence the obsoleting of `TokenType.User` in Discord.NET 2.0+. By forcing your account into using the API, you are risking your account of getting banned by Discord. Because of this, Discord.NET developers are not responsible for any actions or unexpected behaviors caused by this.

Comment: i just want to switch status of user. is this illegal? or dangerous?
it's not problem. i just want to learn that code. i tried to SetStatusAsync. But its not connected to machine. Example: In my machine, im on "Idle". But on connection of discord.net, its just online. I want to get status from machine.

Comment: According to Discord, yes, it is against their API Terms of Service. You can still learn to code - with a bot account.